# python re.MULTILINE confusion

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a simple script that will erase a pre-existing header block from a bunch of Python source code files (amongst other things).  For example:

```
    ##########################################
    ## This is a header block that
    ## I want to erase.
    ## It occurs at the top of a file, 
    ## has a variable number of lines,
    ## and maybe some blank ones thrown in, like
    ##
    ########################################


    this is some code that needs to be preserved

    # and a comment I don't want touched
    followed by some more code...
```

My current approach is to use a regular expression that will grab the whole block and `sub` it with an empty string, like such:

```
    regex = re.compile("^#.*$\n", re.MULTILINE)
    regex.sub('', filetext, count=1)
```

I've tried a hundred variations on that `re` string, including:

```
    "^#.*"
    "^#+.*"
    "^#.*\n"
    ...
```

but all only erase the first line of the block (the line of '#'s at the top).  Python's online documentation says

```
    the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and at the
    beginning of each line (immediately following each newline);
```

which to me means that it will include in a single match all consecutive lines matching the given pattern.  Clearly either my understanding of re.MULTILINE is wrong, or I've written my regexp incorrectly.  Can somebody help me understand what's going on and accomplish what I'm trying to do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the multiline mode, since it is a header, you can use this:

```
^(?:\s*#.*\r?\n)*
```

Without the multiline mode the meaning of `^` is only "start of the string". The precedent pattern will match all consecutive lines at the begining of the string that start with `#` *(with possible white-spaces before)*.

The most important to understand this pattern is that the `.`, by default, matches any characters except newlines. I put at the end of the non-capturing group a CRLF *(i.e. `\r?\n`)* to make the non-capturing group able to be repeated.

When the regex engine encouters a line that don't start with: possible white-spaces + a sharp, the match is ending.

However, since I use `\s*` at the begining of the non-capturing group *(that matches any white-spaces including vertical white-spaces like `\n`)*, the pattern could match something like that:

```
#############
# header
#############

###############
# someting else if there is nothing that starts 
# a newline with an other character than "#"
###############
```

*(In other words, keep in mind that `\s` can match newlines. However, if you want to forbid this behaviour, you can use `[^\S\r\n]` in place of `\s`.)*

I don't think that your understanding of the multiline mode is wrong, but I think that using the multiline mode to find **consecutive lines** is not the best idea.

Comment: Awesome, this works.  Thanks.  Can you explain why my understanding of multiline mode was wrong?  Also, why isn't a regexp compiled with this string clobbering all other comments in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting the regex replace to only 1 replacement max in this line:

```
regex.sub('', filetext, count=1)
```

Get rid of the `count=1`:

```
regex.sub('', filetext)
```

The `count` argument limits the maximum number of replacements, from the docs:

> The optional argument count is the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced; count must be a non-negative integer. If omitted or zero, all occurrences will be replaced.

Comment: if I do that, then all comments in the file will be clobbered as well.  Want I'm aiming for is one match to the entire header that can be clobbered (count=1) and leave the rest alone.